# Tokenize words ignoring hashtags with Open nlp

Tags: java, tokenize, opennlp

I'm trying to tokenize some sentences. For example the sentences :

```
String sentence = "The sky is blue. A cat is #blue.";
```

I use the following command with Open nlp:

```
SimpleTokenizer tokenizer = SimpleTokenizer.INSTANCE;
String[] result = tokenizer.tokenize(sentence);
```

But I want opennlp considers '`#`' as a letter of a word. So '`#blue#`' will be a token.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to create a new Tokenizer object (implementing Tokenizer).

```
Tokenizer t = new Tokenizer() {

    @Override
    public Span[] tokenizePos(String arg0) {


    }

    @Override
        public String[] tokenize(String arg0) {


        }
};
```

Then, Copy/Paste the SimpleTokenizer code into thoses 2 functions.

And Associate the '#' to others alphanumericals values :

```
if (StringUtil.isWhitespace(c)) {
    charType = CharacterEnum.WHITESPACE;
} else if (Character.isLetter(c) || c=='#') {
    charType = CharacterEnum.ALPHABETIC;
} else if (Character.isDigit(c)) {
    charType = CharacterEnum.NUMERIC;
} else {
    charType = CharacterEnum.OTHER;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are just being unlucky, try this:

```
public static void tokenize() throws InvalidFormatException, IOException {
    InputStream is = new FileInputStream("models/en-token.bin");
    TokenizerModel model = new TokenizerModel(is);
    Tokenizer tokenizer = new TokenizerME(model);
    String tokens[] = tokenizer.tokenize("The sky is blue. A cat is #blue. ");
    for (String a : tokens)
        System.out.println(a);
    is.close();
}
```

As you can see, "#blue" is tokenized as a single token. And the intelligence of the Tokenizer remains.
For this to work you will need the "en-token.bin" model for this to work.

Comment: Thanks for this solution ! However i prefer mine. More complex but I don't need to load a file.

Answer (score -1):

you could just try `String[] tokens = sentence.split(" ");`

`split()` is a method of String in java. Passing it a space (i.e. `" "`) will just give you all the tokens in the string delimited by a space

Comment: But OpenNLP is more "intelligent". You can detect the words, the punctuation. For example, "80dollars." => 3 tokens : {"80" , "dollars" , "."}. A split isnt suffisant.

Comment: Right, but here it seems to be too sophisticated for your use case. The less sophisticated .split() will, at least for the String sentence you declare above, do just what you want

Comment: My example was just to illustrate what I want, I really need the nlp tokenizer intelligence

Comment: Ah, I see, not sure I can help you with that :(. Maybe you need to write your own custom tokenizer using classes OpenNLP tokenize package?

Comment: yes ! But i dont know how to do this, I really need something simple. Just add '#' to others 'a-Z' char with a simpleTokenizer instance.